# Android JSONException: Value <script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, c#, android, json, rest

I saw that related questions were posted regarding this issue but none of the solutions worked for me. In my scenario, I get this error when trying to retrieve values from a JSON Response sent by the backend.

**Here's my Raw JSON Response from my Backend:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 516
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=0b;Path=/;Domain=MY-SERVICE-NAME-HERE.azure-mobile.net
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 07:55:00 GMT

{"user":{"id":"349994","firstName":"683hniqnonefw","lastName":"bebweberbw","profilePicture":"683hniqnonefw"},"status":"success","accessToken":"279740","extraData":{"currentAndroidVersion":"4.6.2"}}
```

**The Exception I get in Android Studio:**

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**How I read the values from the response in Android:**

```
URL url = new URL("http://MY-MOBILE-SERVICE.azure-mobile.net/api/loginuser?email=" + email + "&password=" + pass);
HttpURLConnection urlRequest = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlRequest.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlRequest.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
urlRequest.addRequestProperty("ACCEPT", "application/json");
urlRequest.addRequestProperty("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", mobileServiceAppId);

JSONObject[] response = null;

InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlRequest.getInputStream());
BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));


StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder();
String line;

while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
    responseString.append(line);
}

JSONObject jsonobj1 = new JSONObject(responseString.toString());

//Doesn't reach this point. Crashes before this
Log.d("Check", responseString.toString());

String status = jsonobj1.getString("status");

JSONObject jsonobj = jsonobj1.getJSONObject("user");
```

According to what I read on other Stack answers, this happens when there are **unwanted characters in the JSON Response String**. Even though I know the possible reason, I have no idea how to rectify the issue. Can someone please pin point the problem?

**Additional:** Backend Coded in **C#** and hosted on **Microsoft Azure**

**EDIT:**

Hahahaha This is what I got when I logged the Response! No wonder it crashed. BUT the response is okay when I request it via Fiddler or any other client. My Java code seems wrong, Yes thats the actual response I got on the Android. The Fiddler responses seem okay though

```
<script language="javascript">document.location="http://1.1.1.1/process.htm";</script>
```

Comment: you don't have status string in your json how you will be able to get it

Comment: @Earthling Can you log the `responseString.toString()` and post it here.

Comment: @EricB. Sure. Hold on

Comment: getString("status"); where???

Comment: @EricB. Looks like it doesn't reach that point. I edited my Android Code

Comment: @AditayKaushal Check edited java code

Comment: @VivekMishra Edited my java code

Comment: Put the logging before the `JSONObject` construction

Comment: are you getting this  also  in responceHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 516
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=0b;Path=/;Domain=MY-SERVICE-NAME-HERE.azure-mobile.net
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 07:55:00 GMT

Comment: Move the log before this line `JSONObject jsonobj1 = new JSONObject(responseString.toString());`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Edited my code

Comment: @EricB. Oh my goodness.. my java code seems incorrect :O Seems correct to me. I logged it and edited my answer. Hilarious response! The fiddler client and other clients give me the correct response though. What am I doing wrong :O

Comment: It seems from the response, that your service, redirects to another url which returns the actual response. This is handled by fiddler or any other client. Make your HttpUrlConnection handle redirects too.

Comment: @EricB. Sorry I didn't quite understand that. What do you mean 'redirects'? Why does it redirect to another service? Could you show me a a resource I can refer to please?

Comment: The javascript code `document.location="http://1.1.1.1/process.htm";` is used to redirect to this url: `http://1.1.1.1/process.htm`. What happens is you ping url A, url A has javascript code that redirects to url B, which echos your response. Now since your HttpUrlConnection is not following 'redirects', it outputs the actual response it gets from url A, which is the javascript code.

Comment: @EricB. Neat explanation. Grasped it. How can I edit my code to handle redirects?

Comment: Add this line, i think it will resolve your issue: `urlRequest.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);`

Comment: @EricB. No mate. Looks like it doesn't work either

Comment: Where did you add this line?

Comment: @EricB. Right below urlRequest.setRequestMethod("GET");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99785/discussion-between-eric-b-and-earthling).

Comment: check whether you have to specify the formal in the url as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    try {
        // create http connection
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        // connect
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);

        // get response
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if(entity == null) {
            msg = "No response from server";
            return null;
        }

        // get response content and convert it to json string
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        return streamToString(is);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        msg = "No Network Connection";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use optString instead of getString..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is your response redirects to another url, your `HttpUrlConnection` must handle redirects. See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/) on how to do it.